# I am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

```java
package com.example.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;  

import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;

import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration

@EnableAutoConfiguration

@ComponentScan("com.example")

public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean("dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder b = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        b.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample");
        b.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        b.username("postgres");
        b.password("postgres");
        return b.build();
    }

    // sessionfactory bean
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        builder.scanPackages("com.example");

        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    // Hibernate properties:
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    // transaction manager bean
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new 
              HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#88ecc47' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#88ecc47': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Comment: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Comment: Can you add the full Exception logs

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, bean dependency might be causing the issue.

@Added qualifier and @Autowired , @Dependson

```
 @Bean("dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder b = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    b.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample");
    b.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    b.username("postgres");
    b.password("postgres");
    return b.build();
}

// sessionfactory bean
@Bean("sessionFactory")
@DependsOn(value = {"dataSource"})
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(@Autowired  DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

    builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    builder.scanPackages("com.example");

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}

// Hibernate properties:
private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", "true");
    return properties;
}

// transaction manager bean
@Bean
@DependsOn(value = {"sessionFactory"})
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(@Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new
            HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Following is running on my machine for mysql. Something seems wrong in your project

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Bean("dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder b = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    b.url("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/localdb");
    b.username("root");
    return b.build();
}

@Bean("sessionFactory")
@DependsOn(value = {"dataSource"})
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

    builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    builder.scanPackages("com.example");

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", "true");
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn(value = {"sessionFactory"})
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(@Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new
            HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
}


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: you can refer this https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-and-postgresql for more reference on how to connect to postgres and providing properties via yml/property file.